# Failed writes after a while on mounted nfs volume

Tags: debian, filesystems, nfs, kubernetes, nfsv4

I have mounted an nfs drive on the machine. I can see it with the following command:

```
$ df -aTh | grep nfs
… unrelated volumes …
10.200.30.100:/export/pvc-70..1d nfs4  976M  2.0M  907M  1% /var/lib/kubelet/pods/72..1d/volumes/kubernetes.io~nfs/pvc-70..1d
```

[I added ellipsis for brevity's sake.]

I repeatedly write to a file like from the machine itself (but doing this from a container yields the same result)

```
$ while true
  do echo test >> /var/lib/kubelet/pods/72..1d/volumes/kubernetes.io~nfs/pvc-70..1d/data.txt
  sleep 5
  done
```

This works, but after a while I get the error-message:

```
-bash: /var/lib/kubelet/pods/72..1d/volumes/kubernetes.io~nfs/pvc-70..1d/data.txt: Invalid argument
```

This goes on forever, or as long as my patience lasts.
Is there any reason nfs should behave like this? Why does it stop allowing me to write so suddenly?
I tried giving `777` permissions, but this didn't affect anything.
Even creating a new file after about ~38 mins the same problem appears. The file is not writable anymore from the machine. Then, (sometimes) if I read the file, for some reason I can write it again for a while.

I got the following log when the error is occurring:

```
[816270.396574] NFS: permission(0:231/8193), mask=0x81, res=0
[816270.403198] NFS: permission(0:231/8193), mask=0x3, res=0
[816270.406521] NFS: atomic_open(0:231/8193), data2.txt
[816270.412065] --> nfs_put_client({2})
[816270.415211] --> nfs4_setup_sequence clp ffff8fbd383c2800 session ffff8fbcf6fa1800 sr_slot 4294967295
[816270.419180] --> nfs41_setup_sequence
[816270.420853] --> nfs4_alloc_slot used_slots=0000 highest_used=4294967295 max_slots=3
[816270.424797] <-- nfs4_alloc_slot used_slots=0001 highest_used=0 slotid=0
[816270.428181] <-- nfs41_setup_sequence slotid=0 seqid=71351
[816270.430539] <-- nfs4_setup_sequence status=0
[816270.433691] encode_sequence: sessionid=1942:1545315805:1942:0 seqid=71351 slotid=0 max_slotid=0 cache_this=1
[816270.439233] --> nfs4_alloc_slot used_slots=0001 highest_used=0 max_slots=3
[816270.442573] <-- nfs4_alloc_slot used_slots=0003 highest_used=1 slotid=1
[816270.444845] nfs4_free_slot: slotid 1 highest_used_slotid 0
[816270.447379] nfs41_sequence_process: Error 0 free the slot
[816270.451224] nfs4_free_slot: slotid 0 highest_used_slotid 4294967295
```

Interestingly, when it works it doesn't use `atomic_open` but just `open`.
(Source code [here](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/e6b92572808467f35fd159d47c45b650de29e722/fs/nfs/dir.c#L1489))

I thought I could debug this by setting authorisation to NONE instead of the default. How do I do that?

## UPDATE:

I finally managed to reproduce the problem reliably! I turned on logging only for file and I get the following log that shows a transition between when I can write the file without problem and when the operation results in a `EINVAL` error.

```
...
[3533332.934037] NFS: open file(/data13.txt)
[3533332.937896] NFS: flush(/data13.txt)
[3533332.941986] NFS: fsync file(/data13.txt) datasync 0
[3533332.947038] NFS: write(/data13.txt, 33@0)
[3533332.952519] NFS: flush(/data13.txt)
[3533332.962836] NFS: fsync file(/data13.txt) datasync 0
[3533332.965829] NFS: release(/data13.txt)
[3533336.975155] docker0: port 2(veth295ffd2) entered blocking state
[3533336.977344] docker0: port 2(veth295ffd2) entered disabled state
[3533336.984250] device veth295ffd2 entered promiscuous mode
[3533336.995705] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): veth295ffd2: link is not ready
[3533337.061611] nfsd: initializing export module (net: ffff8fbceb052580).
[3533337.263506] eth0: renamed from veth9c5fe34
[3533337.274301] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): veth295ffd2: link becomes ready
[3533337.277259] docker0: port 2(veth295ffd2) entered blocking state
[3533337.279440] docker0: port 2(veth295ffd2) entered forwarding state
[3533337.972794] NFS: open file(/data13.txt)
[3533337.982390] NFS: flush(/data13.txt)
[3533337.984978] NFS: fsync file(/data13.txt) datasync 0
[3533337.991418] NFS: write(/data13.txt, 33@0)
[3533337.998084] NFS: flush(/data13.txt)
[3533338.017990] NFS: fsync file(/data13.txt) datasync 0
[3533338.020636] NFS: release(/data13.txt)
[3533341.385814] NFSD: laundromat service - starting
[3533341.387690] NFSD: laundromat_main - sleeping for 90 seconds
[3533342.869641] NFS: open file(/data.txt)
[3533342.894059] NFS: write(/data.txt, 1@0)
[3533342.896545] NFS: flush(/data.txt)
[3533342.906735] NFS: fsync file(/data.txt) datasync 0
[3533342.910853] NFS: release(/data.txt)
[3533342.914387] NFS: open file(/data.txt)
[3533342.917169] NFS: write(/data.txt, 29@0)
[3533342.920237] NFS: flush(/data.txt)
[3533342.927772] NFS: fsync file(/data.txt) datasync 0
[3533342.931496] NFS: release(/data.txt)
[3533343.002610] NFS: read(/data.txt, 30@30374)
[3533343.233929] docker0: port 2(veth295ffd2) entered disabled state
[3533343.239144] veth9c5fe34: renamed from eth0
[3533343.257428] nfsd_inet6addr_event: removed fe80:0000:0000:0000:f026:2cff:feb1:510b
[3533343.260065] docker0: port 2(veth295ffd2) entered disabled state
[3533343.270280] device veth295ffd2 left promiscuous mode
[3533343.272992] docker0: port 2(veth295ffd2) entered disabled state
[3533343.330925] nfsd: shutting down export module (net: ffff8fbceb052580).
[3533343.337814] nfsd: export shutdown complete (net: ffff8fbceb052580).
```

In the above log I can write the file without problem until the last messages about shutting down the so called `export module`.

Comment: Does this only happen from Docker? Is the NFS server on the same machine? Have you tried `--volume`, instead?

Comment: Looks like docker has lost network connection:
[3533343.233929] docker0: port 2(veth295ffd2) entered disabled state

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor while it is docker that creates the file system, I operate on the bare metal (well on the cloud so virtualised possibly). When I write to the file I do it from the cli of the machine itself.

Comment: @JohnDoe would that influence how opening a file works? Keep in mind that I can still access the file system to open and write other files, it only fails if I repeatedly write to the same file.

Comment: Do you mean you can access other files in the same directory as your inaccessible data.txt file?

Comment: @JohnDoe yes, the problem manifests only with the file. And it’s transitory to some degree.

Comment: To improve your chance of getting an answer: answer all comments fulls, but these clarifications into the question.